# Manually highlight all invalid inputs of Angular Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

The task is kinda primitive.

I got a simple Angular form with various inputs and I'd like to highlight invalid inputs manually (e.g. on submit action).

I tried to loop over invalid inputs, assuming that they must have some method to highlight an error, but unfortunately they don't.

Same with form. `$setDirty()` didn't work as well.

I'm using `ng-form` directive to get access to both form and input.

AngularJS version is 1.2.x.

Comment: First of all you have to precise what the invalid inputs mean to you (empty?), secondly inputs are just html elements so they have not such method as 'highlight on error', just DOM manipulating functions. My advice to you is to consider using angular validation: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form markup should look like, so that when you click on submit ng-class will add `submitted` class on `form` that will give you idea that whenever you have submitted class on form and field has `ng-invalid` class, you can highlight those element

**Markup**

```
<ng-form name="form" ng-class="{submitted: submitted}" ng-submit="submitted=true; submit();">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="formData.firstname">
   <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="formData.lastname">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</ng-form>
```

**CSS**

```
.submitted input.ng-invalid {
   border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, seems like a overthought on that :) Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by ovrerthought??

Comment: Basically, this is CSS solution, I was looking for JavaScript one. But it's redundant here, prolly.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-pattern** and **required** it will check you validation. and onSubmiy you can customized your validation also

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/dmo1jg02/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Js

```
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```